# Python Script Progressively Slows Down

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I am currently working on a Python script that helps me filter bad data out of my large dataset of sentences (for Machine Translation). It does the job so far, but as I move into datasets with 100k+ sentences, that's where problems occur. It starts off fast enough but then progressively gets slower to a point where to finish processing a document would take literal days. I've commented on what each function does but for a quick breakdown:

- It reads a sentence from a file (source) in one language and gets the corresponding line in the other language (target)
- It checks to make sure the sentence is not the same in both files, is not repeated in the file, is of a certain length and contains a certain ratio of characters.
- If **any** of the conditions aren't met, the sentences don't get put into the new files (new_src, new_tgt) and we continue to the next sentence in the file, and if they do meet them, they do go into the new file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import linecache
#from numba import jit, cuda

#Let User define path
path = "/home/justin/opus.txt/"

#Let User define files
source = path+input("Source input:")
target = path+input("Target input:")
new_src = path+input("Source destination:")
new_tgt = path+input("Target destination:")

num = 0
str1 = ""


#Gets Line number of current source sentence
def line_no(file, sent):
    with open(file, "r") as myFile:
        for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 1):
            if sent in line:
                return num

#Writes successful sentences to files (args are new src/tgt files and tgt sentence)
def accept_data(dest_src, dest_tgt, src, tgt):
    with open(dest_src, "a+") as output:
        output.write(src)
    with open(dest_tgt, "a+") as tgtout:
        tgtout.write(tgt)

#Checks to see if the source/target sentences don't match each other
def copy_check(src, tgt):
    if src == tgt:
        #print("The sentences are the same")
        return False
    else:
        return True

#Check to see if a sentence is already in a file
def duplicate_check(src, tgt):
    if len(re.findall(source, src)) > 1 or len(re.findall(target, tgt)) > 1:
        print("This is a dupicate")
        return False
    else:
        return True


def sentence_ratio(src, tgt, threshold=0.6):
    short, long = sorted([len(x) for x in [src, tgt]])
    #print(short/long)
    if short/long < threshold:
        return False
    else:
        return True


def length_check(src, tgt, low_threshold=3, high_threshold=25):
    len_s = len(src.split())
    len_t = len(tgt.split())
    if len_s < low_threshold or len_s > high_threshold or len_t < low_threshold or len_t > high_threshold:
        return False
    else:
        return True


#Check the ratio of sentence characters
def char_ratio_check(src, tgt):
    alpha = r"([A-Z]|[a-z])"
    digits = r"\d"
    whitespace = r"\s"
    total = 0
    iter = 0

    # Count the number of letters, numbers and symbols in a sentence
    for lang in src, tgt:
        num_count = 0
        other_count = 0
        alpha_count = 0
        char_count = 0
        for char in lang:

            if re.match(alpha, char):
                alpha_count += 1
                char_count += 1
            elif re.match(digits, char):
                num_count += 1
                char_count += 1
            elif re.match(whitespace, char):
                pass
            else:
                other_count += 1
                char_count += 1

        # Check to see if 50% or more of the sentence are numbers and letters or if it's all non-letters
        if (alpha_count + num_count) / char_count < 0.5 or num_count + other_count == num_count + alpha_count + other_count:
            #print("This sentence has a bad character ratio")
            total += 1
            # print("This sentence is fine")

        iter += 1

        #Checks for the 2nd iteration. Only proceeds with null int Total value
        if iter == 2:
            if not total:
                accept_data(new_src, new_tgt, src, tgt)
                #print("sentence {} is ok".format(line_no(source,src)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(source, "r+") as f:
        for src_sent in f:
            tgt_sent = linecache.getline(target, line_no(source, src_sent))
            tgt_sent = str1.join(tgt_sent)
            print(src_sent+"\n"+tgt_sent)
            print(line_no(source, src_sent))
            if copy_check(src_sent, tgt_sent):
                pass
            else:
                print("Let's Continue - 1")
                continue

            if duplicate_check(src_sent, tgt_sent):
                pass
            else:
                print("Let's Continue - 2")
                continue

            if sentence_ratio(src_sent, tgt_sent):
                pass
            else:
                print("Let's Continue - 3")
                continue

            if length_check(src_sent, tgt_sent):
                pass
            else:
                print("Let's Continue - 4")
                continue

            char_ratio_check(src_sent, tgt_sent)
```

I really do apologies if certain points of my code seem off, I'm still not the best and I only ever thought I'd be the only one to look at the code. 
If I had to guess, the problem stems from something to do with reading/appending to files, but I'm not sure what.

I'd appreciate any assistance on this because I don't see this as a sustainable way to process my datasets going forward.

Kind regards,

Justin

Comment: I/O operations are really expensive. Try to minimize the time you open files and read/write from them.

Comment: @Capie I feel like instead of breaking them up into separate functions, it could all be done in one (and thus on file read), but many things online or tutorials make you feel like you're doing something wrong for doing that, unless it really is in all circumstances? Also, would it be worth putting the sentences that pass the filters into a dict. or list and then transfer that to a file, or would that be of any benefit?

Comment: Tutorials are made to cover basic principles. You are trying to manage a large dataset and it needs to be efficient, otherwise it gets slow. What I would suggest you is to use iterator to read the whole file and then process it. For the write data, the same, save it memory and either write it at the end or by chunks (depends how big is the data.)

Comment: A lot of things are unknown/hidden from our point of view, so it is very hard to find where is the problem. How big is the input computed data? How many files are used? How often `accept_data` is called? Apart from that, please do not call `re.match` for each character. This is slow! Prefer buffered parsing (using regexp quantifiers) or just use the fast `.isalpha`/`.isdigit`/`.isspace` built-in Python functions. I also think `accept_data` is the source of the slowdown here, because the OS may not be able to append data to the file without copying again previous data (so in `O(n^2)` overall).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Well the inputted files are about 700k sentences long/130mb in size, which each sentence coming in at about 15 words or so. There are 2 of these files (because if I discard of an English sentence, I must do the same to the sentence in the other language). And accept data is called only if it passes all 5 filters (usually for about 50% of the sentences). I never knew of those built-in `is` functions, I'll definitely try them out. And yes, the appending may be the problem. Do you think it would be worth creating new files every few thousand sentences or so and merging them myself?

Comment: @JustinCunningham Yes, this is a good idea. You could also merge them automatically at the end of this script (without the append mode). I also suspect the `linecache.getline` to be slow. It may be a good idea to load the whole file if it fits in memory. It is important to **profile** your program to easily check if such performance hypothesis are true. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html).